# Is it wishful thinking to believe there must be a god as there would be no justice for unpunished criminality?

Tags: belief, justice

I'm sorry if this is not an appropriate question for this site, and i apologise for the lack of depth to my belief in a God. I know nothing of the bible but i have faith there is a god.

I have stated the above as the basis of my belief in God on other websites and have been told by atheists that such a belief is wishful thinking. I have responded to their comments as to why an atheist would wish for oblivion in death?. Is this a good rebuttle of their statement that I am wishful thinker?

Comment: Welcome. It has bern said thst it takes more faith to be an atheist then it does to believe in an intelligent creator     Your question will likely be closed. Please take the  tour mentioned in your welcome email.   Or click  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Philosophical point that ends with "*therefore there must be a god?*" can usually be countered with "*surely that proves that there's no god?*". Plenty of evil people seem to do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it wouldn't be wishful thinking as much as it would be the temper of a burdened heart that's suffered its own injustice.

There's nothing wrong with coming to an understanding of the larger scope of cosmic "checks and balances," as long as its your belief.

Personally, I hold a belief in karma - but not in the way of "you did this to me so this is going to happen to you". In fact, I don't even humor rationalizing the equation of cosmic - or more correctly by your question - Theological Justice.

It's impossible to measure, equate or understand the physical, mental, emotional or spiritual suffering that has been placed on another. Yes, we can "imagine how they feel" but until you're actually in that person's mind and have gone through their lifetime of ups and downs, there's no way to calculate the pain they feel to a standard precedent you could then use to inflict a level of pain on another and call it justice.

Even the proverbial "eye for an eye" is written and scribed by man. It shows the imperfect nature of our mentality towards those who cross a line against a rule we've collectively agreed upon to be law of the land.

Truthfully, the only real way to answer your question would be to first ask yourself about your own thoughts towards God and your faith in your religious practice. After all, you're asking in such a way that it would define God as being a wrathful bringer of justice. True, this is in line with Traditionalists Christian thinking and echoes through the writing of the Old Testament, but then comes the New Testament and an introduction to God who is more driven by love, learning and understanding.

In essence it depends on how you feel. If you feel that God exists as simply a way to balance the scales and provide a few examples of half-given explanations to a host of questions that neither man or science can explain or answer, then yes. You would be answering your own question in its asking.

If you believed differently and thought that life is a struggle we all have to journey and there's really no rhyme or reason to the events - good or bad - that unfold for us, then you would have your answer as well.

See, we can have as many bibles, books and sacred teachings of any degree or facet on the history of Spirituality or Religion, but at the end of the day the books are simply meant to be reflections penned to be passed down so it could be shared with others in hopes they would find a level of faith and enlightened hope from the content. It was never meant to be taken LITERALLY, even can when it was being written.

First, we're all imperfect people and through 2,000 years of interpretations, translations and variations in the beliefs of the one choosing to grant what's what as the final copy, it's not feasible that the exact texts we have today in any religious tradition are the intact-actual teachings given back on that day.

Second, there's a large margin of error for getting many things lost in translation when many of the gospels were given in the way of analogy or stories told to further the point and clear explanation of the purpose of the sermon.

Despite our leap in evolution to the point we stand today we're really stupid people when you want to be honest. Our brains don't accept data blindly without purpose or explanation. This is why there's all these stories that you're told that contain the message the Religion is teaching, but it's delivered in such a way that we can understand it, let it marinate and sit with it for awhile in our own contemplation and because the message wasn't simply weighed down in archaic 'law if the land' language but instead given life and something to identify ourselves or find empathy in our brains are going to hold stronger to and recollect even faster from that story.

I've kind of gone beyond the point of the question here, but not really. I think it's a great question actually and something to think about. What is your relationship with your God? How do you see your God? What does your God do or how does he behave?

I'm using specifics here because despite this being a Christian forum it can be used to question against any faith for anyone. And it should. We should never blindly follow something just because its all we know and we should stop and think about things like this. Your relationship with your Creator and the light you see your God shining in are more important than anything else - period. Forget about scripture, religious law and tradition - none of that matters if you're following it with an empty or unclear stance on the most important relationship you'll ever have.

I was raised Christian and I'm no longer a follower, but I still have respect for the teachings-it just wasn't my path to journey in this lifetime. Still, in my own Day to Day Spiritual Practices and engagement of prayer and perspective I've often checked in on this topic and asked how do I see my God? How well do I know him? Do I even like him? Would I know him if we crossed paths in the grocery store? Etc.

To question and to seek acceptable answers that can yield the comfort of closure, man will go to and length and never be stopped until his mind put at ease. We were meant to question, to explore and experiment. Without there being an alternative factor to choose from for a Patron God/Goddess and having only the concept of Christianity available to you - how would God know you really chose him with a whole heart? You can have the strongest faith in the world but until its tested or questioned by one means or another and you're given options, no one can say for certain which way they may turn.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that there is, within humanity generally, not only a social conscience regarding co-habiting, procreation, family life, community life, national life, international life, but also an admiration of nature, of creation ; and also, as you say, a conscience regarding not only one's own behaviour but the justice involved in judging, correcting and punishing bad behaviour in others : all of this points to the fact that man is made in the image of God.

We are not just brute beasts ; we have deep, deep - very deep - instincts as to right and wrong, good and evil, justice and injustice.

Whence these instincts ?

The generality of mankind is appalled at atrocities, turns away from bestiality, shuns brutality, embraces genuine affection; ; resists evil behaviour and, the rather, applauds good works and charitable actions.

Where do these traits come from ?

True, some humanity revels in obnoxious ideals, propagates harmful habits, fosters abnormal conduct and descends even to the depths of such outright criminality that society has to imprison these elements in order to protect itself.

But most do not. The majority have a conscience.

All of which cries out that there is a God in heaven.

And that we are his creation.